# updates are not reflected on ui even when reading the providers with ref,watch() in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

when it first launched, I used a future provider and made it run data fetching, the fetched data are saved to a list as "Question" Objects. When I try to manually add a "Question" object to the List, I can see the length of the List get updated but The updated element is not rendered on screen

```
import 'package:ai_and_r_app/conntrollers/auth_controller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:ai_and_r_app/conntrollers/text_identification/text_controller.dart';
import 'package:ai_and_r_app/conntrollers/text_identification/text_state.dart';
import 'package:ai_and_r_app/provider/providers.dart';
import 'package:ai_and_r_app/screens/auth_screen.dart';
import 'package:ai_and_r_app/screens/content_add_screen.dart';
import 'package:ai_and_r_app/widgets/body/recognized_question_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class HomeScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/home-screen';
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
  void handleLogout() {
    ref.read(authControllerProvider.notifier).logout();
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

// this is the FutureProvider function for Data Fetching.
    final getAllQuestions = ref.watch(getAllQuesionsProvider);

// this textcontrollerprovider is a statenotifierprovider where I
// defined the add Question function.  and try listening to it's state 
   
 ref.listen<TextState>(
      textControllerProvider,
      (previous, next) {
        if (next is TextStateSuccess) {
          // rebuilds the ui
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
    );

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: const Text('AI&R'),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
              color: Colors.white,
              position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                return [
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: handleLogout,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.logout,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      label: const Text(
                        'Logout',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        elevation: 4,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ];
              },
              child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 10,
                  ),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.person_2_rounded)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
// here, Data is fetched and Added to the list, and I'm using a stateprovide to watch the
//questionlistprovier so when the question is added to a list, UI can rebuild to reflect data
        body: getAllQuestions.when(
            data: (_) {
              final questionList = ref.watch(questionListProvider);
              
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: RecognizedQuestionList(
                    recognizedQuestionList: questionList),
              );
            },
            error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(error.toString()),
            loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () =>
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ContentAddScreen.routeName),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const AIandRFooterContainer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is how the providers are designed

```
final getAllQuesionsProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  final questionService = ref.watch(questionServiceProvider);
  return questionService.getAllQuestions();
});

final questionListProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  final questionService = ref.watch(questionServiceProvider);
  return questionService.questions;
});

// question service is the service class that have functions on question add and question list, question add function triggered through a statenotifierprovier
```

Question class and question add and get all questions

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:ai_and_r_app/utils/dio_instance.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import 'package:ai_and_r_app/models/recognized_question.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class QuestionService {
  List<RecognizedQuestion> _questions;

  QuestionService(this._questions);

  List<RecognizedQuestion> get questions {
    return [..._questions];
  }

// add question (mcq)
  Future<String> addNewQuestion(
      String userId,
      String subject,
      String examYear,
      String examTypeId,
      String examQuestionTypeId,
      String questionNumber,
      String? obtainedText,
      String? translatedText,
      File? imageFile) async {
    try {
      final formData = FormData.fromMap({
        'subject': subject,
        'examYear': examYear,
        'examTypeId': examTypeId,
        'examQuestionTypeId': examQuestionTypeId,
        'examQuestionNumber': questionNumber,
        'questionOriginalText': obtainedText,
        'userId': userId,
        'files': await MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile!.path,
            filename: basename(imageFile.path))
      });

      final dioInstance = await DioInstanceUtils().getDioInstance();

      final response = await dioInstance.post(
        '/api/v1/question/create',
        data: formData,
      );

      final result = response.data['question'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final message = response.data['message'] as String;

      final question = RecognizedQuestion(
          id: result['questionId'],
          subject: result['subject'],
          examYear: result['examYear'],
          examTypeId: result['examTypeid'],
          questionTypeId: result['examQuestionTypeid'],
          questionNumber: result['examQuestionNumber'],
          obtainedText: result['questionOriginalText'],
          translatedText: translatedText,
          isReviewed: result['isquestionReviewed'],
          imagePath: result['questionFilePath']);

      _questions.add(question);

      return message;
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      if (e.response != null) {
        final message = e.response?.data['error'];
        throw Exception(message);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
        final message = e.message;
        throw Exception(message);
      }
    }
  }

 

// get all questions
  Future<void> getAllQuestions() async {
    try {
      final dioInstance = await DioInstanceUtils().getDioInstance();

      final response = await dioInstance.get(
        '/api/v1/question/all',
      );

      final results = response.data['questions'] as List<dynamic>;

      final newList = results.map((question) {
        final newq = RecognizedQuestion(
            id: question['questionId'],
            subject: question['subject'],
            examYear: question['examYear'],
            examTypeId: question['examTypeid'],
            questionTypeId: question['examQuestionTypeid'],
            questionNumber: question['examQuestionNumber'],
            questionSectionNumber: question?['examQuestionSectionNumber'],
            questioPartNumber: question?['examQuestionPartNumber'],
            obtainedText: question['questionOriginalText'],
            translatedText: '',
            isReviewed: question['isquestionReviewed'],
            imagePath: question['questionFilePath']);

        return newq;
      }).toList();

      _questions = newList;
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      final message = e.message;
      throw Exception(message);
    }
  }


}
```

this is how te statenotifier is defined

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:ai_and_r_app/conntrollers/text_identification/text_state.dart';
import 'package:ai_and_r_app/provider/providers.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class TextController extends StateNotifier<TextState> {
  final Ref ref;

  TextController({required this.ref}) : super(const TextStateInitial());

  void addQuestion(
    String userId,
    String subject,
    String examYear,
    String examTypeId,
    String examQuestionTypeId,
    String questionNumber,
    String? recognizedText,
    String? translatedText,
    File? image,
  ) async {
    state = const TextStateLoading();

    try {
      final response = await ref.read(questionServiceProvider).addNewQuestion(
          userId,
          subject,
          examYear,
          examTypeId,
          examQuestionTypeId,
          questionNumber,
          recognizedText,
          translatedText,
          image);
      state = TextStateSuccess(response);
    } catch (e) {
      state = TextStateError(e.toString());
    }
  }


// here, I've add getall questions as a statenotifier, but
// I used it from a Futureprovider , not from here   

  void getAllQuestions() async {
    state = const TextStateLoading();
    try {
      await ref.read(questionServiceProvider).getAllQuestions();
      state = const TextStateSuccess(null);
    } catch (e) {
      state = TextStateError(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

final textControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TextController, TextState>(
    (ref) => TextController(ref: ref));
```

Based on my knowledge I think the updates are not reflected on UI because of the future builder, which shows the state where the data is available Since that fetched state didn't change, It never reflected any updates even though the Question objects are added, and even when watching the list with the provider. I would appreciate any suggestions and improvements to resolve my issue

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `ref.watch(questionListProvider)` inside the `data` callback of `getAllQuestions.when`. You should put `ref.watch(questionListProvider)` in the `build` method unconditionally.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final questionList = ref.watch(questionListProvider);
  
  // ...
}
```

If `questionListProvider` needs `getAllQuesionsProvider` to complete first before it starts exposing values, make `questionListProvider` a `FutureProvider` that awaits the `future` of `getAllQuesionsProvider`.

```dart
final questionListProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  await ref.watch(getAllQuesionsProvider.future);
  final questionService = ref.watch(questionServiceProvider);
  return questionService.questions;
});
```

Now instead of using `.when` on `getAllQuesions`, you should use `.when` on `questionList`.

---

Please also note that `StateProvider` is now **discouraged**. See: [Migration guides > From StateNotifier](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/from_state_notifier).

I also recommend you to look at the whole [Riverpod docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/introduction/why_riverpod) to know best how to use providers to handle your case.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, As you suggested, I want to read `getAllQuestionsProvider`  before `questionListProvider`. I have tried adding them both in `build` before, but when adding them like that, It didn't provide the right output due to it reads `questionListProvider ` which is empty initially. I implemented the suggested approach but it seems it still not reflecting the updated data in the UI. Will try going through the docs again. Thank you for the support @Dhafin Rayhan